# jQuery PHP: Check if username already exist

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to check the existence of an username already registered on my application using jQuery+Ajax+POST.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-md-3 control-label">Username</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3" id="userCheck">
    <div class="alert alert-info" id="userCheckLabel"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#username').focusout(function() {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    checkUserExist(username);
})
function checkUserExist($uname) {
    $.post( "../core/lib/checkUserExist.php", function( data ) {
    if(data.html == 'true') {
       $('#userCheck').slideDown("slow");
       $('#userCheckLabel').text("This user already exist!")
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require_once('../../core/class.user.php');
$user = new USER();
$uname = $_POST['username'];

$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT user_nameFROM users WHERE user_name=:uname ");
$stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row['user_name']==$uname) {
    print 'true';
} else {
    print 'false';
}
?>
```

I Don't include class.user.php cause It's only handling the PDO Connection, If I remove the `if(data.html == 'true')` the connection work as expected and the message come out.

**Behavior**

The code work if I remove the `if(data.html == 'true')`. but with this it doesn't do anything, no errors in console. So I think the error is in the way I handle the PHP part.
Any suggestion?

Comment: you don't sent the username `function checkUserExist(uname) {
    $.post( "../core/lib/checkUserExist.php", {username: uname },  function( data ) { ...`

Comment: I got unexpected token function

Comment: i have missed comma

Comment: @splash58 thanks to you and Alive to Die the code is working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are returning string not HTML, so you have to do like below:-

```
$.post( "../core/lib/checkUserExist.php",{username: uname }, function( data ) {
     console.log(data);// check this and let me know the output
     if(data == 'true') {  // or try if(data)
       $('#userCheck').slideDown("slow");
       $('#userCheckLabel').text("This user already exist!")
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, using your suggestion I don't get the alert regarding the user exist

Comment: Ok, was a typo in the file path, now it's working as expected, thanks!

Comment: @andreaem  glad to help you:):)